# Blade Not Passing Data To Controller Laravel

Tags: attributes, laravel-8, laravel-blade

This is my blade

```
<div class="modal fade" id="delete-document-modal-lg{{ $Document->id }}" >
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">Delete</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <form  method="POST" action="{{ route('document-tracking.destroy',[$Document->id] )}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {{ csrf_field() }}
      @method('DELETE')
      <div class="modal-body"> You sure you want to delete PDN: <b>{{ $Document->PDN }}<b>?</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn gray btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"> Cancel </button>
          <button type="SUBMIT" class="btn gray btn-danger"> Delete</button>
      </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

this is my controller

```
public function destroy( Document $Document) {

  $this->authorize('delete', $Document);

  
  $Document->delete();
 
 return redirect()->route('document-tracking.index')->with ('success', 'Document Deleted Successfully!');
    
      }
```

This is my route

```
Route::resource('document-tracking', ('App\Http\Controllers\DocumentTracking\DocumentController'));
```

when I return $document with this code

```
return $document;
```

i got the [ ] result.

Can anyone help me solve this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't post ALLCAPS, it's considered shouting/rude.

Comment: Typo: `$document` vs `$Document`